# how to view an array in HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, object

So I want the array that I get back when I input a manufacturer to show the complete data from each object inside the array in the HTML. However when I call the function in the HTML page I only get back the word object however many times the Manufacturer is defined in the original array. Could anyone help please?

```
// To make program read the data inside the array cars and pick the ones with the      desired manufacturer//
function findManufacturer(manufacturer) {
    var retcars = [];
    for (i = 0; i < cars.length-1; i++) {
        car = cars[i]
        if (car.manufacturer == manufacturer) {
            retcars.push(car)
        }
    }
    display(retcars);
}

function display(mycars) {
    document.getElementById('mycars').textContent= mycars;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the simplest level, you could just use `JSON.stringify`.  That's mostly useful for debugging, though:

```
function display(mycars) {
    document.getElementById('mycars').textContent= JSON.stringify(mycars);
}
```

---

You could also iterate through the array, and then through the properties of each car, generating some dynamic HTML:

```
function display(mycars) {
    var html = '';
    for (var car in mycars) {
        for (var prop in car) {
            html += prop + ': ' + car[prop];
        }
        html += '<hr/>';
    }
    document.getElementById('mycars').innerHTML = html;
}
```

---

Ideally though, you would want to be able to write an HTML template to display the data.  I recommend taking a look at some client-side templating engines like [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) or [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/).  These engines allow you to write an HTML template with tokens to represent the data fields:

```
<script type="text/template" id="car-template"> 
    <% _.each(cars, function(car) { %>
        <div>
            <div><%= make %></div>
            <div><%= model %></div>
        <div>
        <hr/>
    <% } %>
</script>
```

Then you simply write something like this:

```
function display(mycars) {
    var template = _.template(document.getElementById("car-template"));
    var html = template({ cars: mycars });
    document.getElementById('mycars').innerHTML = html;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I finally got it :)

Answer (score 0):

`mycars` is an array, so you can't set the text content of an element to be the array...that's why you're getting the famous [Object object] string.

You need to parse the array and turn it into some sort of HTML before inserting it into the DOM.

Try something like this, where we put the contents of mycars into a table and then put it into your `<div id="mycars">`:

```
function display(mycars) {
    var table = '<table>';
    for (var i = 0; i < mycars.length; i++) {
        table += '<tr>';
        foreach (var prop in mycars[i]) {
            table += '<td>' + mycars[i][prop] + '</td>';
        }
        table += '</tr>';
    }
    table += '</table>';
    document.getElementById('mycars').innerHTML = table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try those changes:

```
function display(mycars) {
  document.getElementById('mycars').innerHTML= mycars.toString();
}
```

Comment: Please note, `toString()` does not extract properties, it just displays the "[object]" string (it's actually identical to the OP code, which does an implicit string conversion).

Answer (score 0):

**Advanced use of `JSON.stringify`**

```
var x={a:"hello",b:[1,2,3]},
    y=function(a,b){return typeof b==='string'?undefined:b},
    D=document;

D.body.appendChild(D.createElement('pre')).textContent=JSON.stringify(x,y,' ');
```

**Description**

```
JSON.stringify(Array,ReplacerFunction,SpaceToUse)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

The `replace` function allows you to replace some values inside the array/object before creating the text string. In my case i exclude strings.

**Element `pre`**

Also i like to use pre as it's preformatted, so `'\n'` is a new line `'\t'` is a tab, in my example i have a simple white space.

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/T8u32/

with replacer function

http://jsfiddle.net/T8u32/1/